# Archive settings in Microsoft Outlook 2016, do not migrate any mail located in subfolders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, archiving, microsoft-outlook-2016

So, I've been experimenting with a few computers, and various settings, but the long and short is that Outlook 2016 seems to simply ignore all subfolders when archiving.

Here are my steps:

```
MailBox Layout:

Inbox
-- Subfolder 1
-- Message 1
-- Message 2
-- -- Subfolder 2
-- -- Message 3
-- -- Message 4
```

I go to **File > Info > Tools > Clean up old items** and select **Archive this folder and all subfolders**.

From here, I choose **Subfolder 1**, my date range (*which I confirm includes email in Subfolder 1 and 2*), my archive location, and click **OK**.

When my archive is complete, it resembles this:

```
Archive Layout:

Inbox
-- Subfolder 1
-- Message 1
-- Message 2
-- -- Subfolder 2
-- -- 
-- --
```

The **Subfolder 2** is created, but no messages are migrated.

Any idea how I can archive subfolders in Outlook 2016?

*Note, I have also tested this with the AutoArchiving settings, with the exact same result.

Comment: For *Archive this folder and all subfolders*, to what do you set *Archive items older than* and could it affect the archiving?

Comment: Its set to 1 day or older, which encompasses everything pretty much